# Determinant of a matrix which is given as the difference of certain column vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_0, \ldots, v_n$ be $n$ dimensional vectors. Assume that $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are linearly independent.

Prove  that

$$
\det \left( \left[v_1 - v_0 , v_2 - v_0, \ldots, v_n - v_0 \right] \right) = \det \left( \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\v_0 & v_1 & \ldots & v_n\end{bmatrix} \right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Just perform columns operations to transform
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
v_0 & v_1 & \dots & v_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
to
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
v_0 & v_1-v_0 & \dots & v_n-v_0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
without changing the determinant.